# Scaling forward variable in Inhomogeneous Hidden Markov Model

Tags: hidden-markov-model

## Background

### Ordinary HMM

Consider an ordinary Hidden Markov Model $\lambda = (\pi, A, B)$ with $N$ hidden states $\{1, 2, ..., N\}$ and $M$ observation symbols $\{v_1, ... v_m\}$. Let's denote a state $i$ at time $t$ as $q_t$. Then

- $\pi$ is the initial distribution $\pi_i = \mathbb{P}(q_1 = i)$
- $A$ is the transition matrix $a_{ij} = \mathbb{P}(q_{t} = j \mid q_{t-1} = i)$
- $B$ is the emission matrix $b_j(k) = \mathbb{P}(v_k \text{ at time } t \mid  q_t = j)$

A lot of calculations are performed using the **forward variable**
$$
\alpha_t(j) = \mathbb{P}(O_1, ..., O_t, q_t = j \mid \lambda) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N \alpha_{t-1}(i)a_{ij}b_j(O_t)
$$
One of the greates limitations of ordinary Hidden Markov Models is that the state occupancy is modeled as the geometric distribution. The probability of $t$ consecutive observations in state $i$ can be written as
$$
d_i(t) = a_{ii}^t(1-a_{ii})
$$

### Inhomogeneous HMM

One of the solutions to that problem is using the so-called Inhomogeneous Hidden Markov Model (IHMM), as described [here](https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings-article/icassp/1992/00225892/12OmNBOllfJ). The whole idea revolves around modifying the transition matrix $A$ so that it is time-variant
$$
a_{ij}(d)
$$
where $d$ describes duration of a given state. In this setting, there is a new formulation of forward (and backward) variables
$$
\alpha_t(j,d) = \mathbb{P}(O_1, ..., O_t, q_t = j, d(q_t) = d\mid \lambda): \begin{cases} \alpha_{t+1}(j,1) &= \sum\limits_{\tau=1}^t\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \alpha_t(i,\tau)a_{ij}(\tau)b_j(O_{t+1})\\
    \alpha_{t+1}(j,d+1) &= \alpha_t(j,d)a_{jj}(d)b_j(O_{t+1})\end{cases} 
$$
where $d = 1, ..., t$.

## Problem statement

In the ordinary HMM, the values of $\alpha$ exponentialy approach $0$ as $t \to \infty$, so there always exists time stamp $t$ beyond which we surely exceed the precision range. However, there is a pretty straightforward solution, namely **scaling**:
$$
\hat \alpha_t(j) = \alpha_t(j) \cdot \dfrac{1}{\sum\limits_i^N \alpha_t(i)} = \alpha_t(j) \cdot c_t \ \ \ \forall_t
$$
As the impact of $\alpha_{t-1}(\cdot)$ on $\alpha_{t}(\cdot)$ is multiplicative, we can easily retrive all the scaling coefficients $c_t$ and take them into account in the further inference, i.e. parameter reestimation.

Now the problem is, that scaling cannot be performed for IHMM, as the impact of $\alpha_{t-1}(\cdot, \cdot)$ on $\alpha_t(\cdot, \cdot)$ **is not** multiplicative (i.e. it involves summation for $d=1$, that appears also in $d>1$). What's more, geometric decay happens not only for $t$, but also for $d$. So finally, here arises my question: is there any possible solution to that problem? I tried using log-domain with log-sum-exp trick, but that unfortunately doesn't work (it would take me a while to present why, but to put it short: $\log x$ maps $(0,1) \to (-\infty, 0)$, so to retrive $x$ we need to perform $e^x$. Although log-sum-exp trick allows us to shift values of $x$, if there is a huge range of values of $x$, which happens to be the case for even not so large $t$ and $d$, we still have a huge power in $e^x$).